# How to get the new Android progress view that is in 4.0?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

I have just tried implementing a ProgressBar with the following two styles:

- `?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge`
- `?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall`

However, they are the old, vanilla progress spinners that Android has always had.  See below:

[image: Old vanilla progress bar]

I'm looking for the progress bar that comes with the 4.+ theme.  It's the one that has one progress indicator rotating clockwise, and a semi-transparent indicator running counterclockwise at a slower pace.  The heads then intersect at 5 points (star formation) across the circle, like the image below.

[image: New yummy progressbar]

How do I get this `ProgressBar` in my app?

Comment: Are you using Theme.Holo or its variants?

Comment: Unfortunately my minSdk is 7, so no.

Comment: Do you want to have the new style in Android 11+ and the old one in previous versions? Or are you looking for the drawable itself to include in your application for all API versions?

Comment: Yeah I'd like for the ProgressBar to use the Holo drawable when it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a custom theme, then have it inherit from `Theme.Holo` in API level 11+, and from `Theme` for all others (or their light variants). To do so, see [Select a theme based on platform version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme).

That way the `progressBarStyleLarge` attribute will be mapped to the new resource (`progress_large_holo`) in devices that support it. This will also change all other resources though (such as backgrounds for EditText, &c).